# How to georeference multispectral raster without loss of data

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, overlay, vegetation-index

I am trying to align two rasters made of data captured during same flight, but with separate cameras (drone - onboard, and Micasense RedEdge) and two separate gps devices (drone and another one feeding data to RedEdge).

Since both cameras are taking pictures independently and both gps chips feed data with their own error the result is a mismatch of overlaid rasters - clearly visible by using vector lines indicating rows.

[image]
[image]

My goal is to overlay the rasters in a way that vector layer indicating rows would have same position on both maps. I do not need absolute accuracy therefore in my trials I used data from RGB raster to georeference index map. But after doing so - I loose all values in the index map receiving only black raster with range of values "nan - 0"

How to set up the georeferencer (transformation settings etc. ) to avoid this such situation?

Comment: What's the range of values for the index raster? It sounds like they're decimal values between 0 and 1, and the georeferencer is outputting a raster with integer values. So all values get rounded to the nearest integer.

Comment: Slightly below zero and also slightly beyond 1. They were decimals indeed. Should I first reclassify the raster or maybe it would be better to georeference base rasters for each band?

Comment: It seems the georeferencer can only produce TIFF format. According to (ESRI Help on Raster file formats](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/supported-raster-dataset-file-formats.htm), this format can do multi-band with integer values, or single-band with decimal values, but not both. So you can either convert to integer values or georeference the individual band rasters. It seems like georeferencing the separate bands could lead to mis-alignment between the bands.

Comment: Thanks. I re-run whole map generating process again and problem disappeared. However: as soon as I'll have enough time for sure will return to to this issue to investigate it deeper. It should not remain without clear answer :)